# Generate Textfield as per number given by user in java

Tags: java, swing, frame

Requirement is like:

I want to take input values from user in frame but no of inputs is also decided by user.

So first,

In frame,I want user to write no of values in one text field 
so as soon as user writes that many text fields should be generated in the same frame.

How can this be done?
Is this possible or is there any good way available for this?

Comment: i am new to Swing so only thing I know is simple making of frame and JOptionPane

Comment: The [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) gives a good introduction to JTextFields. Try to write some code and post a new question if you encounter specific issues.

Comment: @JeremyD its not a homework and I am not a student...only thing is that I am database person and new to JAVA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a table instead. Either the user can directly edit the table or you provide a "Add New Row" button. In my opinion changing the UI layout (adding text fields) at runtime is bad design.

Comment: can you explain more precisely?